# Android null Pointer Exception in GridView on Scrolling down

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

In my application I have  to display n number of  items  to the user ,lets say  25 items and out of 25 items ,  20  items are displayed  to the user  . When I scroll down I can see the remaining 5 items and click on the 25 item I am getting a  crash .

Your help is appreciated .

MyCode is as follows :

```
                gridViewItems.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                final int position, long arg3) {

Log.e("PickfoodItems",".getChildAt(position)"
    + gridViewItems.getChildAt(position) + position);
```

gridViewItems.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundResource(R.color.Tan);/  Null pointer Exception

```
}
    });
```

Comment: please help me I  am stuck at this point .

Comment: Have you found a solution?